# I can print_r array value, but not check it in if statement

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a PHP function and getting this error I don't understand...

`print_r($my_array);` will output

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [field_id_41] => 
    ) 
)
```

but if I try to do

```
if ($my_array[0]['field_id_41'] == "some value")
```

I get the error

> Undefined offset: 0

I've tried `$my_array['0']` but that doesn't make a difference. I'm able to assign the value to another variable, and print that, but for some reason using it for the if statement breaks it.

I'm really not sure what's going on here... Any help appreciated.

EDIT: here's the actual loop I'm having trouble with

```
foreach($counsellors_result as $one_counsellor) {
    $this_time_out_query = ee()->db->select('field_id_41')
        ->from('channel_data')
        ->where('entry_id', $one_counsellor['parent_id'])
        ->get();

    $this_time_out = $this_time_out_query->result_array();
    $time_out_status = $this_time_out['0']['field_id_41'];

    if ($time_out_status != "Time Out") {
        ee()->db->insert(
            'relationships',
            array(
                'parent_id' => $entry_id,
                'child_id' => $one_counsellor['parent_id'],
                'field_id' => 111
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `$my_array[0]['field_id_41']` seems okay. Please put your code here.

Comment: As Sahil wrote - put your code. Not part, whole code.

Comment: out Your code please.

Comment: Also share `var_dump($this_time_out)`.

Comment: `field_id_41` that's the column-name, do you by chance have columns named `field_id_1`, `field_id_2` and so on, up to 42?

Comment: You getting value of `$this_time_out ` in a loop and in one iteration its being empty and you are getting this error this empty value for `$this_time_out`

Comment: @SahilGulati `var_dump($this_time_out)` will give me `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["field_id_41"]=> string(0) "" } }`

Comment: @Qirel yes, there are values for all of these. I'm building on top of the ExpressionEngine CMS, that's native EE naming stuff.

Comment: @user2486 that would make sense yes!

Comment: @rorycaraher There is a loop around your code just check `var_dump` within the loop. Might be this `$this_time_out` will be coming out as empty array.

Answer (score 0):

try this way its help full

```
<?php

$this_time_out=array (0 => array ( 'field_id_41' =>""));

$time_out_status = $this_time_out[0]['field_id_41'];
if($time_out_status != ""){
    echo $time_out_status;  
}else{
    echo "no any value<br><br>";
}

//print "no any value"

$this_time_out=array (0 => array ( 'field_id_41' =>"test"));

$time_out_status = $this_time_out[0]['field_id_41'];
if($time_out_status != ""){
    echo $time_out_status;  
}else{
    echo "no any value";
}

//print "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you var_dump in every loop iteration? I can guess that you get array(array('field_id_41'=>'')) in the first iteration but null in the second iteration. When you look at the output you can't see var_dump(null).

Please try to dump it that way:

```
$i = 0;
foreach (...) {
   //...
   var_dump(array('i' => $i, 'var' => $time_out_status));
   $i++;
   //...
}
```

You'll probably see that in the second iteration you get:

```
array('i' => 1, 'var' => null)
```